# Right way to manage Arrays with intersecting types and narrow them back down

Tags: typescript, union-types

When using arrays with different Types in typescript I tend to run into issues with properties that are not on all Types.

I ran into the same issue for different types of sections on a page, different roles of users with different properties and so on.

Here is an example with animals:

For example, if you have types Cat, Dog and Wolf:

```
export type Cat = {
    animal: 'CAT';
    legs: 4;
}
export type Dog = {
    animal: 'DOG',
    legs: 4,
    requiresWalks: true,
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 5
}
export type Wolf = {
    animal: 'WOLF',
    legs: 4,
    requiresWalks: true,
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 20
}
type Animal = Cat | Dog | Wolf;


const animals: Animal[] = getAnimals();
animals.forEach(animal => {
    // here i want to check if the animal requires a walk
    if (animal.requiresWalks) {
        // Property 'requiresWalks' does not exist on type 'Animal'. Property 'requiresWalks' does not exist on type 'Cat'.
        goForAWalkWith(animal)
    }
});
// The type "AnimalThatRequiresWalks" does not exist and i want to know how to implement it
goForAWalkWith(animal: AnimalThatRequiresWalks) {

}
```

As commented above, property requiresWalks can not be used to narrow down the type.

Also imagine we have 20 animals. I am having difficulties implementing types that may extend animals like "AnimalThatRequiresWalks" which may have multiple properties related to walking animals.

What is a clean implementation to join these types with a type "AnimalThatRequiresWalks" (with properties "requiresWalks true" and "walkDistancePerDayKm") and how can i properly narrow it down to "AnimalThatRequiresWalks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions:

1. How do you check `requiresWalks` to see if the animal requires a walk?
2. How do you define the type for `animal` in `goForAWalkWith`?

Re #1: You test to see if the object has the property before you try to use it (this is a specific type of narrowing the handbook calls [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)):

```typescript
animals.forEach(animal => {
    if ("requiresWalks" in animal && animal.requiresWalks) {
// −−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        goForAWalkWith(animal)
    }
});
```

Re #2, you can extract from the `Animal` union all types that are assignable to `{requiresWalks: true}` via the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```typescript
function goForAWalkWith(animal: Extract<Animal, {requiresWalks: true}>) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

`Extract<Animal, {requiresWalks: true}>` is `Dog | Wolf`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBDeBeOBvAKDmLgwDsBLAWwwBsAuOAcjQEEAVJgbiJNuADmAZ0YAWHgF8CoSLATJUAEQgC4uQiVKUaDZooDyAcSYAaXsX7CxZzVGABHAK4U7QgOp0A1iIRRHwGxIAdy9FCiEYcgBjYAAFYChFDEQAaSpGAFYCKRloeCQUODcIWgAzNXxzLWo6RiY3fQAZADFTKssfUUDiOycXYHcvHxg-AKqQ2k8wiOi4hKTU9LgAJgAGbIIC1FZtOgrMeAAfOGVVY+KyngIAE2Ao2gw7OCiIMgjqnR8dmtoAbQBdLhwAD0wIqAmAMG+nwAFABKHjkH5CAB0pWgAFEMFEABYwpE6NQAPkqmgo5RhACJes5XB5JkJKXAKGQPnsAGTstm0FE0-qDBlw0maEgCCDNaCsemeNwUGB4gl0OFVKQSBEEAilRxkKIwCivOBiiVQKVeWXy-G7XQYkAjbEwAA80LoJnwfLpQ0YI38EiJQo0JBebxKwBRtBUVMMEDg6KgpDgE08CblOIQONQTIA1NyUYraOqJEA)

You con't have to do that inline if you don't want to, you can define a type alias for it, then use the alias:

```typescript
type AnimalThatRequiresWalks = Extract<Animal, {requiresWalks: true}>;
// ...
function goForAWalkWith(animal: AnimalThatRequiresWalks) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBDeBeOBvAKDmLgwDsBLAWwwBsAuOAcjQEEAVJgbiJNuADmAZ0YAWHgF8CoSLATJUAEQgC4uQiVKUaDZooDyAcSYAaXsX7CxZzVGABHAK4U7QgOp0A1iIRRHwGxIAdy9FCiEYcgBjYAAFYChFDEQAaSpGAFYCKRloeCQUODcIWgAzNXxzLWo6RiY3fQAZADFTKssfUUDiOycXYHcvHxg-AKqQ2k8wiOi4hKTU9LgAJgAGbIIC1FZtOgrMeAAfOGVVY+KyngIAE2Ao2gw7OCiIMgjqnR8dmtoAbQBdLhwAD0wIqAmAMG+nwAFABKHjkH5CAB0pWgAFEMFEABYwpE6NQAPkqmgo5RhACJes5XB5JkJKXAKGQPnsAGTstm0FE0-qDBlw0maEgCCDNaCsemeNwUGB4gl0OFVKQSBEETYKODQujsHFYABKDlpA2lQgqGJAI2xMAAPDraCZ8Hy6UNGCN-BIiTxQSQAHoAfgIvvYWvCJxUcHOJVKGtKjjIURgFFecDFEqgUq8svl+N2ugdesNxv5ZqFGhILzeJWAKNoKiphggcHRUFIcAmng7cpxCBxqCZAGpuSjFbR1RIgA)

---

In the comments, you've said you'd like to define all of the `AnimalThatRequiresWalks` properties together in an explicit type for it rather than inferring that type from `Dog`, `Cat`, etc. You can do that:

```typescript
interface AnimalThatRequiresWalks {
    animal: string;
    requiresWalks: true;
    preferredWalkTerrain: "hills" | "paths" | "woods";
    walkDistancePerDayKm: number;
}

export type Cat = {
    animal: "CAT";
    legs: 4;
};
export type Dog = AnimalThatRequiresWalks & {
    animal: "DOG";
    legs: 4;
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 5;        // Only needed if you want to refine its type
    preferredWalkTerrain: "paths";  // Same
};
export type Wolf = AnimalThatRequiresWalks & {
    animal: "WOLF";
    legs: 4;
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 20;       // Only needed if you want to refine its type
    preferredWalkTerrain: "woods";  // Same
}
type Animal = Cat | Dog | Wolf;

declare const animals: Animal[]; // = getAnimals();
animals.forEach(animal => {
    if ("requiresWalks" in animal && animal.requiresWalks) {
        goForAWalkWith(animal)
    }
});

function goForAWalkWith(animal: AnimalThatRequiresWalks) {
    console.log("Go for a walk with the " + animal.animal);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwCoAWcYAShAI4CuwUEAzgOq4DWdyA3gFDI-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-0AqBgJYUD2X3ftB37HZlX2G8vx-LgdC7HtpQgNccDWC9bgJTcoD4HFVHeMC6gIFAXAAagfQQ1wg4pOCAA)

You might want to experiment with that to see what the developer experience is like. It's **really** easy to forget to put that `AnimalThatRequiresWalks &` part on when defining `Dog`, `Wolf`, etc., and the type of `AnimalThatRequiresWalks["animal"]` is `string` whereas when you infer it is it's the more narrow `"Cat" | "Dog" | "Wolf"`. But it may be more convenient.

It occurs that one way to address the ease of forgetting `AnimalThatRequiresWalks &` at the beginning is to use a generic type for animals:

```typescript
interface AnimalThatRequiresWalks {
    animal: string;
    requiresWalks: true;
    preferredWalkTerrain: "hills" | "paths" | "woods";
    walkDistancePerDayKm: number;
}

type AnimalType<R extends boolean, Type extends object> =
    R extends true
    ? AnimalThatRequiresWalks & Type
    : Type;

export type Cat = AnimalType<false, {
    animal: "CAT";
    legs: 4;
}>;
export type Dog = AnimalType<true, {
    animal: "DOG";
    legs: 4;
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 5;        // Only needed if you want to refine its type
    preferredWalkTerrain: "paths";  // Same
}>;
export type Wolf = AnimalType<true, {
    animal: "WOLF";
    legs: 4;
    walkDistancePerDayKm: 20;       // Only needed if you want to refine its type
    preferredWalkTerrain: "woods";  // Same
}>;
type Animal = Cat | Dog | Wolf;

declare const animals: Animal[]; // = getAnimals();
animals.forEach(animal => {
    if ("requiresWalks" in animal && animal.requiresWalks) {
        goForAWalkWith(animal)
    }
});

function goForAWalkWith(animal: AnimalThatRequiresWalks) {
    console.log("Go for a walk with the " + animal.animal);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwCoAWcYAShAI4CuwUEAzgOq4DWdyA3gFDI-JwbYcALmR0wUUAHMA3N160qNekxysR4yhFm9kAB1oxotACYrmeI3FAiARAWA4cdG8gA+yG7uIFnbjwHcAe0DjZ21efxYAEWAxfiQABWgouABPAGlMERBKTAAjaFkAX05OMFTdFHQsXDwKiAAeEmQIAA9IEFDkPOCcCH4AGmQ6ypb2iE62QLyAKwgEMAA+ZABeOR5mto6ujQh15AB+NAFaolIKalpGFjYAMmH6-ZERrVK23UCoMGRy0YBhYirY41fD1BrwJwQIZcHT8EG2P6oPA2cI8PqSOgiAAsxUWsnen2+vxQUUCkiB1UELwau2h+zhglsUQA8gBxFH7dGY5A4-aRVQxOIgRLJNKZEQAVmkOh0AHpZchmSAcKlkCAIBBjJrkMAYMhUoFKMhIuAfoFkAZQChgGA2MT9voIIYoCYzBYXVYQLYvGAfCiePLkABlOCYPZFPGcAlfH71ZAMQI4PUrYFUsG0jj0k7CDwMZkAGQAYhydFzsajjdFYmB4hAklAUhkssgAEwABmlMuQgaVKrVGq1xh1eoNRpNRPNlvVOttscqDoMRk1bss1gCwVC-u7CpDYc4EdkxNTuCBAO+7lJ5PcCaTsk4WoQODgtGQCECIDEfGz3MpuAA2gAutKgYppIEBgL+TgABQAJSyAyuB0AAdDAnwAKKIAQUEITgqzLDCvC6sgUE2AolzKDcLigF+ILILc9w4UhZFKNcqh0DBmZdjwkiBIWnyoGYDA2lhOEwfsJRFHBpQwJQwpgMA77IDxfFQAJLBCb62HZiIkGEMQZCKFcZjsZxvBvh+iYQEhOBkiRrLmqhUB8JWqjGsJPwECgLgANQ0YISGicUnBAA)

Maybe that's better, or maybe it's over-engineered. :-D

Comment: Amazing, i thought `"requiresWalks" in animal && animal.requiresWalks ` were basically the same so i didnt consider that, and Extract seems to have been just the missing puzzle piece to implement functionality for parts of the array! I think it might be even better if i could define some properties on `AnimalThatRequiresWalks `, is there a clean way to do that or would you avoid it?

Comment: @JeremiasNater - Glad that helped. :-) Where would those properties come from? Remember that `AnimalThatRequiresWalks` is just `Dog | Wolf`, so if you added properties at the level you're defining `AnimalThatRequiresWalks`, it wouldn't just be `Dog | Wolf` anymore and `Dog` and `Wolf` instances wouldn't fit the definition. (But you can add properties to a type you create via `Extract` or similar, by doing an intersection: `type AnimalThatRequiresWalks = Extract<Animal, {requiresWalks: true}> & {/*more props here*/};`. That's useful in other situations, but I don't see how it helps here.)

Comment: The thing is that your answer solves the problem, but i think in my real world cases it would be nice to define which properties some type of item requires. For example, in my current project i have page sections and some of them are "breakable" meaning that a page-break can be within them. To calculate the page break position, these sections must have "headerHeightObserver" and "entryHeightObservers" and for the type check i would like to use "section.isBreakable". With your solution i can add those properties to all affected sections, but i cant define what defines a BreakableSection.

Comment: @JeremiasNater - Can you do a TypeScript playground of the situation you're describing? I'd like to help and I'm sure there's a way to address it, but I'm having trouble visualizing what you're describing.

Comment: I think the sections example overcomplicates the problem. Its just that i want to define the type `AnimalThatRequiresWalks` with its required properties in one place instead of extractimg them, and use that to extend the union types. The advantage of this would be that if i want to createa new Animal that requires walks, i can see whats needed for that in one type declaration instead of getting some kind of overlap of the types with Extract. A potential property for this example would be `preferredWalkTerrain`, which in my case would be needed for a new animal that requires walks.

Comment: I made it work using the "in" type guard, thanks alot. I Can't currently edit your answer since the edit queue is full, here is the playground (i had to shorten it because of comment character limit): shorturl.at/nGM09. Maybe you can improve on it and add it, otherwise i will try to add it when the queue is no longer full.

Comment: @JeremiasNater - I've updated the answer with a couple of other options. I'm afraid I didn't see your second comment until after I'd done that. Also, I can't get that link to open, I just get taken to the page on that service where I can shorten a link. (BTW: https://tsplay.dev/ is a good way to do short links to the TS playground, and is allowed by SO's code that otherwise blocks URL shorteners.) But please don't edit other solutions into the answer. You can always post your own answer if you have alternative solutions. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry for my link not working. Your solution is Perfect though, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243682/discussion-between-jeremias-nater-and-t-j-crowder).